# Fabric crashes after the update : [Fabric isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10c0bb918

Tags: ios, swift, google-fabric

Today fabric crashes after the pod update

Fabric 1.9.0

```
[Fabric isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10c0bb918
```

Crashing line :

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

It crashes at app startup. Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: Did you add the Fabric key with it's info in your info.plist file?

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi yes

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10? If yes you need to add your app's built info.plist location to the build phase's input files

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi yes xcode 10. How can i do that?

Comment: Go to run script you have added for Fabric in Build Phases and add this line in input file field : $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi didnt work. still crashes

Answer (score 5):

I reverted to a previous version of Crashlytics by updating my `Podfile`

```
pod 'Fabric', '1.8'
pod 'Crashlytics', '3.11'
```

Then updating Cocoapods:

`pod update 'Crashlytics'`

Hopefully Google fixes this soon

Comment: I did the same. :(

Comment: I'm surprised so few people are experiencing this issue, must be specific to our setups? Either way, feel free to accept this answer ;)

Comment: @Lewis42 I had never had to deal with something like that where the Crashlytics tool itself is the one casing the crash :D

Comment: @hamada147 me neither :) In one of my other apps it worked fine so it must just be affecting a small group

Comment: @Lewis42 I do think so as well because this is only affecting some of my apps only as well.

Comment: Has anyone reported the bug to them?

Comment: Can't believe this is still an issue :/

Comment: This is STILL an issue!

Answer (score 1):

This was still happening in a project of mine, and I've just been using out of date Fabric & Crashlytics as in @Lewis42's *solution* above.

We needed to update Fabric so I've persevered with it today. Updated to the latest pods for both Fabric & Crashlytics, and the crash happened again at startup as previously.

I'm sure I've tried this previously, but this time I did the following:

1. Uninstalled both pods by commenting them out in the podfile, and ran a `pod install`.
2. Made sure there was no Fabric or Crashlytics folders or frameworks in the project or pods folders. There was a Fabric.framework in the main project folder, that I think I'd added as an attempt to fix this issue previously, so I deleted that.
3. Uncommented the two pods in the podfile and ran a `pod install`.
4. Built the app and it finally ran successfully with the updated pods!

Hopefully nobody is still having this issue, but if you are, then this might help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the "Update via Manual Steps" and download the zip file. Here is the link: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update?type=manual
2. Unzip, copy and replace the frameworks (Fabric and Crashlytics)

It worked for me

Comment: Not for me. FWIW, the app that's crashing is Swift-based and shares the frameworks with an action extension. Another Swift app w/no extension works OK. No idea if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by that fact that Fabric SDK's version is incompatible with Crashlytics SDK's version. I happened to stumble on this pitfall when I ran 'pod update Fabric'.

This updated the Fabric SDK but not the Crashlytics. And the problem occurred.

However, Crashlytics SDK's podspec file specifies a dependency on Fabric and also the compatible versions of this dependency. This is what I assumed from the Podfile.lock file:

```
   - Crashlytics (3.8.6):
     - Fabric (~> 1.6.3)
```

So, if the version range specification '(~> 1.6.3)' is correct, even though I ran 'pod update Fabric', this problem shouldn't occur. However, it did. So, my conclusion is the version range specification contains incompatible versions.

My solution is to run 'pod update Crashlytics' only and updated the Crashlytics and also its dependencies.

If this doesn't solve your problem, try removing Fabric and Crashlytics and adding the latest version back.