# Fabric is crashing after latest update (1.9.0) on [Fabric isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

After running a pod update my app now crashes on launch when it hits:

`[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];`

The error returned is:

```
2019-01-11 14:07:15.935040+0000 Leave[26155:181825] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Fabric isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b8354c8'
```

I am using Xcode10.1, in a project built in Objective-c but with some Swift tests and cocoapods. 
I already have the API key in my info.plist and have a run script in my Build Phases.

Before I roll back to the previous version, is there any thing I can try to fix this?

Comment: please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507754/fabric-crashes-after-the-update-fabric-iscrashlyticscollectionenabled-unrec

Comment: And which of those answers is supposed to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should use `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` (as per https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install).
By the way, both Fabric and Crashlytics are now part of the Firebase framework, so I am not even sure this method still works. I'd personally suggest you migrate your project to Firebase to keep it working once the plug is removed from the old Crashlytics environment

Comment: Tried that, it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

For me downloaded sdk from [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/update?type=manual) 
again adding it project worked. hope this may help someone.